# Calendar think current day is the beginning of the

Tags: php

I have been putting a weekly view calendar together that lets the user move back or forwards a week using buttons on a form.  Everything works well except that when the calendar first opens it this that the current day if the beginning of the week so the rest of the days are all out.

Here's what I have so far...

```
if(isset($_POST['add_week'])){
     $last_week_ts = strtotime($_POST['last_week']);
     $display_week_ts = $last_week_ts + (3600 * 24 * 7);
} else if (isset($_POST['back_week'])) {
     $last_week_ts = strtotime($_POST['last_week']);
     $display_week_ts = $last_week_ts - (3600 * 24 * 7);
} else {
    $display_week_ts = floor(time() / (3600 * 24)) * 3600 * 24;
}

$week_start = date('d-m-Y', $display_week_ts);

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $current_day_ts = $display_week_ts + ($i * 3600 *24);
    echo date('d-m-Y', $current_day_ts); 
}
```

I know what the problem is, the line

```
$display_week_ts = floor(time() / (3600 * 24)) * 3600 * 24;
```

It calls the current day but $week_start needs to be the first day of the week but I have tried everything I can find.  I have tried

```
$display_week_ts = strtotime("Monday noon");
```

which seems to work well until the diary reaches Monday 29th October at which point it seems to skip a day and makes 29th October a Tuesday instead.

I found another topic on this site that found the beginning of the week but I have been unable to implement any of them successfully

I will be very grateful for any assistance in this matter, I've been working on it for three days now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$display_week_ts = floor(time() / (3600 * 24)) * 3600 * 24; 
$dow = date("w", $display_week_ts);
$dow = ($dow + 6) % 7;
$display_week_ts -= $dow * 3600 * 24;

$monday = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $display_week_ts));
```

Now `$monday` contains the date for Monday of the current week.  Store this object in the session.  When you need to move to next week, find the next Monday with

```
$monday->modify('+1 week');
```

To find the previous Monday, use

```
$monday->modify('-1 week');
```

After finding the new Monday, store it back into the session.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much that, how would I incorporate that into my code?  It works fine until I tried to move to next or last week

Comment: @user1267224 When you display the first week, store in session the value of `$display_week_ts`. Then when moving to next week, add `3600*24` to that value and store back into session.  Similarly, subtract when moving to previous week.  You can then always use this value as the starting day of the calendar.

Comment: HI, I managed to get it working but what happens now is the same this when I used strtotime('monday noon'), it skips a day when it reaches 28th october 2012.  It might be because this is the same day British summer time ends and the clocks go back an hour

Comment: @user1267224 I updated my answer to use a different technique - give it a try.

Comment: Hi again, still not working, strngest this is that as soon as I add the line '$monday = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $display_week_ts));' half of the div's on my page disapear for no reason!!  The biggest problem I have though is that when I do try to save $monday in a session and then use $monday = $_SESSION['monday']; $monday->modify('+1 week'); I get this error 'Warning: DateTime::modify() [datetime.modify]: The DateTime object has not been correctly initialized by its constructor'.  Sorry for being a pain

Comment: @tatty27 What php version are you using? This could be because older versions of PHP do not support DateTime completely

Comment: HI again Aleks, it's 5.2.17, I found somewhere that it doesn't support dateTime sessions.  It's ok now though, I've managed to get it up and running (3 days later).  Thank you so much for your help though, I'll mark the question as answerd because it was, thank you

Comment: @tatty27 Yeah, 5.2 has a lot of limitation that have been overcome in 5.3.  I strongly suggest that you upgrade if/when you have a chance. I went through this pain once, about 6 months ago, and never look back.  And it's not that much pain, either.